How to Verify PDF Digital Signatures with Python
I am creating a Django app to verify PDF digital signatures, commonly used in Indian government IDs like Aadhaar, ration cards, and tender documents. However, I am unsure how to verify these digital signatures using Python.
Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this? Any libraries or code examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

This is, unfortunately, off-topic for SO. You can read about what makes a good on-topic question here. This falls under the category of "seeking recommendations for books, libraries, etc"

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
